# Gnuplot using odd number of lines and even number in the same graph from a same file

Tags: linux, graph, gnuplot, benchmarking

I have a file which has this values (fio mixed read write result):

```
1191, 3987, 0, 0, 0
1191, 11781, 1, 0, 0
2193, 4006, 0, 0, 0
2193, 12431, 1, 0, 0
3195, 3698, 0, 0, 0
3195, 11680, 1, 0, 0
4196, 3897, 0, 0, 0
4196, 11407, 1, 0, 0
5198, 3845, 0, 0, 0
```

I want to draw a lines connected together the even numbered lines separately, and the odd numbered separately.

I'd like to use something like this, but this doesn't work:

```
plot "<(sed -n 'p;n' 8k-mix_iops.4.log)" using $1/1000):2 title "25-75 write" with lines, "<(sed -n 'n;p' 8k-mix_iops.4.log" using ($1/1000):2 title "25-75 read" with lines
```

Or I could use somehow the every command but how can I define every second line but start from the 1st line or start from the 2nd line?

```
plot "8k-mix_iops.4.log" every 2 using ($1/1000):($2) title "25-75 write" with lines, "8k-mix_iops.4.log" every 1 using ($1/1000):($2) title "25-75 read" with lines
```

Comment: `this doesn't work` - How does it not work? Does it display incorrectly? Does it fail with an error message? Please include error description - "doesn't work" is a very vague.

Comment: @RebronTreborn Problem solved? Any response would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Every `"` `(` you need to close in proper order.

```
plot "<(sed -n 'p;n' file)" using ($1/1000):($2) title "25-75 write" with lines, "<(sed -n 'n;p' file)" using ($1/1000):($2) title "25-75 read" with lines;
```

Draws for me:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason to use sed. In the gnuplot console type `help every` to get an understanding what `every` does.

**Code:**

```
### plot odd and even rows
reset session
set datafile separator comma

$Data <<EOD
1191, 3987, 0, 0, 0
1191, 11781, 1, 0, 0
2193, 4006, 0, 0, 0
2193, 12431, 1, 0, 0
3195, 3698, 0, 0, 0
3195, 11680, 1, 0, 0
4196, 3897, 0, 0, 0
4196, 11407, 1, 0, 0
5198, 3845, 0, 0, 0
EOD

plot $Data u ($1/1000):($2) every 2 w l title "25-75 write", \
     '' u ($1/1000):($2) every 2::1 w l title "25-75 read"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]